# Show $\alpha_R:\mathbb{Z}[[t]]\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}R\to R[[t]]$ is an isomorphism for $R=\mathbb{Z}/I$ but not for $R=\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I want to see this result from commutative algebra:

Let R be either $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/I$ for some ideal $I\subset \mathbb{Z}$. Let $i:R\to R[[t]]$ be the inclusion, and $j:\mathbb{Z}[[t]]\to R[[t]]$ be the inclusion if $R=\mathbb{Q}$, and the map induced by reducing coefficients modulo $I$ otherwise. Let $\alpha_R:\mathbb{Z}[[t]]\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}R\to R[[t]]$ be the unique map corresponding to $i$ and $j$.

Can you show $\alpha_R$ is an isomorphism for $R=\mathbb{Z}/I$ but not for $R=\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried, and where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** When $R = \Bbb Z/I$, show that $\alpha_R$ is an isomorphism by showing that it is a homomorphism, and then showing that the map is both injective and surjective. Proving injectivity requires that you deal with the definition of the tensor product in some way.

When $R = \Bbb Q$, the map $\alpha_R$ fails to be surjective.  In particular, we can show that the power series 
$$
f(t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-k} t^k
$$
lies outside the range of $\alpha_R$.